# How to deserialize XML when nested object has a namesapce

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

Given the following XML:

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <title>Title One</title>
  </webPart>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <title>Title Two</title>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

And the following c#:

```
[XmlRoot("webParts")]
public class webParts : List<webPart>
{
    static public webParts FromXml(string path)
    {
        webParts returnValue = null;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(webParts));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            returnValue = (webParts)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public class webPart
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the XML. I don't have control over the XML, I can change the c#. If I remove the namespace in the webPart element, can do this during deserialization, it works fine. However, seems kind of kludgy. I feel there should be XML attributes added to the classes, yet can't find the right combination of Namespace tags. The above code deserializes webParts, yet has a count of 0, none of the webPart elements are deserialized. What should be done to the c# in order to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is (in most cases) a very easy task to build the classes from a XML using VS.

- Copy the XML string into the clipboard
- In VS menu [EDIT/Special Paste/Paste XML as Classes](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/)

The XML from your question will be converted to that structure

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute( "code" )]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute( AnonymousType = true )]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute( Namespace = "", IsNullable = false )]
public partial class webParts
{

    private webPart[ ] webPartField;        

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute( "webPart", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3" )]
    public webPart[ ] webPart
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.webPartField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.webPartField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute( "code" )]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute( AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3" )]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute( Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3", IsNullable = false )]
public partial class webPart
{

    private string titleField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and that can be used to convert your xml

```
public partial class webParts
{
    static public webParts FromXml(string path)
    {
        webParts returnValue = null;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(webParts));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            returnValue = (webParts)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That answer brought a tear to my eye. Thank you Sir Rufo! Never knew that was in VS.